# How to reduce android default keyboard size?

Tags: android

when I turn my device into landscape mode, the keyboard is over half of the screen.
Is there any way to reduce android keyboard size or reduce its character size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.. Only thing you can do is to create your own keyboard.

Comment: Even if possible the result would be an awful break in the user experience.

Comment: Exactly, and not assured to work since user can install other custom keyboards and switch between them in settings..